# Is xhr.withCredentials making POST endpoints vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: csrf, ajax, cors, crossdomain

From what I've seen, someone can add the following code to a malicious site (lets say: http://sth.malicioussite.com) and be able to perform ajax post requests to a 3rd party site, along with any cookies set before:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://mysite.vulnerablesite.com/mysite/deleteUser");
xhr.withCredentials=true;
xhr.send(["userId=5"]);
```

If you test this on a browser, you will get an error on the console ( Cross-Origin Request Blocked), but the **request will actually be sent**. What you are not allowed is just to see the result of the request.

If this is not a problem of the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials), or a chromium/firefox implementation issue, then what should be the protection from such attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an AJAX request, the standard approach to exploit this issue would be:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="http://mysite.vulnerablesite.com/mysite/deleteUser" >
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="5">
</form>
<script>document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('myform'));</script>
```

You can also send JSON formatted values (use `enctype="text/plain"`). You cannot however change the `Content-type` header to JSON or add a custom header like `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest`. The thing is, you can't do that with your AJAX example either.

In your example, the browser sees that you are sending a request that is perfectly allowed, so it doesn't ask the receiving server for its CORS policy (thus saving a request). It just sends the request and - depending on the response - allows or disallows reading of the response.

Now, if you were to add a custom header like `xhr.setRequestHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest")`, *then* you are asking the browser to do something which may violate the cross origin policy. Now, the browser will first issue a preflight OPTIONS request. If it is allowed to perform a request it will do so, otherwise it will not.

To prevent CSRF, you should use some [token based defense](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#primary-defense-technique). Because of the way CORS works, you could also check the presence of special HTTP header like [XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#use-of-custom-request-headers) for a less secure CSRF protection.